# What is the meaning of ذَٰلِكَ أَدْنَىٰ أَلَّا تَعُولُو in 4/3?

Tags: tafseer, surat-an-nisa

I read this verse and found that the last part of the verse is translated wrong by almost *all* translators. What is the correct translation of

> ذَٰلِكَ أَدْنَىٰ أَلَّا تَعُولُوا

According to google it has a translation of

> "The lowest not count"

Which makes sense but almost all translators skip this part. My questions are

1. What is the correct literal meaning of the above text?
2. If google translator is correct, does that means this verse was translated wrong by almost all well-known translators?
3. What is the contextual meaning of this part of the verse?

[image]

Translation of 4/3 by major translators

> Sahih International
>
> And if you fear that you will not deal justly with
> the orphan girls, then marry those that please you of [other] women,
> two or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then
> [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more
> suitable that you may not incline [to injustice].
>
> Muhsin Khan
>
> And if
> you fear that you shall not be able to deal justly with the
> orphan-girls, then marry (other) women of your choice, two or three,
> or four but if you fear that you shall not be able to deal justly
> (with them), then only one or (the captives and the slaves) that your
> right hands possess. That is nearer to prevent you from doing
> injustice.
>
> Pickthall
>
> And if ye fear that ye will not deal fairly by
> the orphans, marry of the women, who seem good to you, two or three or
> four; and if ye fear that ye cannot do justice (to so many) then one
> (only) or (the captives) that your right hands possess. Thus it is
> more likely that ye will not do injustice.
>
> Yusuf Ali
>
> If ye fear that
> ye shall not be able to deal justly with the orphans, Marry women of
> your choice, Two or three or four; but if ye fear that ye shall not be
> able to deal justly (with them), then only one, or (a captive) that
> your right hands possess, that will be more suitable, to prevent you
> from doing injustice.
>
> Shakir
>
> And if you fear that you cannot act
> equitably towards orphans, then marry such women as seem good to you,
> two and three and four; but if you fear that you will not do justice
> (between them), then (marry) only one or what your right hands
> possess; this is more proper, that you may not deviate from the right
> course.
>
> Dr. Ghali
>
> And, in case you fear that you will not act
> equitably towards the orphans, then marry such women as is good to
> you, two, three, four, (Literally: in twos and threes and fours) then,
> in case you fear that you will not do justice, then one (only), or
> what your right hands possess. That (way) is likelier you will not be
> in want (Or: you will have too many dependents).

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think Google Translate translates verses at all. Even standard Arabic seems to be wide of the mark most of the time. The translation you enfolded in your question doesn't seem to be *standard grammatical* English either.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer is inside your question: Most of the translations listed in the question provide a good attention to this part. These are the sections of the listed translations that belong to ذلک ادنی الا تعولوا

- That is more suitable that you may not incline [to injustice]
- That is nearer to prevent you from doing injustice.
- Thus it is more likely that ye will not do injustice.
- That will be more suitable, to prevent you from doing injustice.
- This is more proper, that you may not deviate from the right course.
- That (way) is likelier you will not be in want (Or: you will have too many dependents).

تعولوا comes from عول that means oppression, injustice, incline or aberrance.

ادنی comes from دنی and means closer or nearer.

ذلک refers to فَوَاحِدَةً أَوْ مَا مَلَکَتْ أَیْمَانُکُمْ that means a single [marriage] or [the captives and the slaves] that your right hands possess

[Google translator](http://translate.google.com/) is useful for basic translation, but for a technical translation like the holy Quran it's better to use [this website](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=4&verse=3).

Comment: can you provide online arabic dictionary that I can use for reference. My check says ذَٰلِكَ this أَدْنَىٰ  inferior أَلَّاno  تَعُولُو count. Thanks

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter Updated the answer.

Comment: can you give me the correct literal meaning of this text (first part of my question), I agree with the rest of your answer. In other word, regard of it is mention in Quran, what is it meaning as you would understand in everyday arabic. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add to @Ali's answer that the word `"تعولوا"` can have [two different meanings](http://baheth.info/all.jsp?term=%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7) in Arabic:

- To be in need because of having too many dependents, or
- To be unjust

Most interpretations confirm that in this Ayah it refers to injustice. Ibn Kathir discused it in his interpretation:

> That is nearer to prevent you from Ta`ulu,
>
> > meaning, from doing injustice.
>
> Ibn Abi Hatim, Ibn Marduwyah and Abu Hatim Ibn Hibban, in his Sahih, recorded that Aishah said that,
>
> > ذَلِكَ أَدْنَى أَلاَّ تَعُولُواْ (That is nearer to prevent you from Ta`ulu, means, from doing injustice.
>
> Ibn Abi Hatim reported from Ibn Abbas, Mujahid, Ikrimah, Al-Hasan, Abu Malik, Abu Razin, An-Nakhai, Ash-Sha`bi, Ad-Dahhak, Ata Al-Khurasani, Qatadah, As-Suddi and Muqatil bin Hayyan that;
>
> > Ta`ulu means to deviate (from justice).

([Arabic source](http://www.qurancomplex.com/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=katheer&nSora=4&nAya=3#4_3), [English source](http://www.quran4u.com/Tafsir%20Ibn%20Kathir/004%20Nisa.htm))